# Flutter "is not a subtype of type" | Is there a way to know which key is causing the failure?

Tags: flutter, dart, quicktype

I'm trying to parse a JSON into a model in Flutter.
But I get this error a lot

```
'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Which indicates that the model is expecting a Map but is getting a String instead.

My question is, is there a way to know which JSON key is causing that failure?!
instead of printing the JSON and comparing the keys with the models

something like

```
parsing 'country' failed
'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but if you run in debug mode and put a breakpoint where it parses the json you can step through it  and find the one causing an error. If you have lots of things in your JSON and don't want to step through one by one, you could put a try catch around the parsing method, and put your breakpoint in the catch so that when it fails just check (assuming you're using vscode) the variables on the left and see what point it got up to.

Comment: Thanks, @shed, your comment was actually helpful

Comment: you can also create a PODO (Plain Old Dart Object) for the json and check if the object is not returning any error to ensure parsing is done properly. Ref: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-b7f991611d3e